# Prove uniform convergence of $\sum_{e \in \xi} \langle Th, e \rangle e$ for $\| h \| \leq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\xi$ be a basis for Hilbert space $H$. From Parseval's Identity, for every $x \in H$ we have $x = \sum_{e \in \xi} \langle x, e \rangle e$. Thus, for every bounded operator $T : H \rightarrow H$ and for every $h \in H$, exchanging $x$ with $Th$, we have $Th = \sum_{e \in \xi} \langle Th, e \rangle e$. So, for every $h \in H$, the series $\sum_{e \in \xi} \langle Th, e \rangle e$ is convergent. Show that if $T$ be a compact operator, then convergence of the generalized series $\sum_{e \in \xi} \langle Th, e \rangle e$ for $\| h \| \leq 1$ is uniform.

I don't have any idea to prove this statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each finite subset $F \subset\subset \xi$, define
$$
P_F(x) := \sum_{e \in F} \langle x,e\rangle e
$$
By what you are given, the net $\{P_F\}$ converges strongly to the identity.

Let $S = \overline{T(B)}$ denote the closure of the image of the unit ball under $T$, and note that $S$ is compact. For each $y \in S, \exists F_y \subset\subset \xi$ such that
$$
\|P_F(y) - y\| < \epsilon \quad\forall F \subset \subset \xi, F_y \subset F
$$
Now prove that $\exists$ a neighbourhood $U_y$ of $y$ such that
$$
\|P_F(y') - y'\| < 2\epsilon \quad\forall y'\in U_y, \quad\forall F \subset\subset \xi, F_y \subset F
$$
By compactness of $S$, there are only finitely many such $U_y$ that cover $S$, and so $\exists F_0 \subset \subset \xi$ such that
$$
\|P_F(y) - y\| < 2\epsilon \quad\forall y\in S, \quad\forall F \subset \subset \xi, F_0 \subset F
$$
But this means that
$$
\|P_FT - T\| \leq 2\epsilon \quad\forall F \subset\subset\xi, F_0 \subset F
$$
which proves what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. How do you prove that there exists a neighbourhood $U_y$ of $y$ such that...?

Comment: Use the fact that $$\|P_F(y') - y'\| \leq \|P_F(y') - P_F(y)\| + \|P_F(y) - y\|  + \|y - y'\|$$ and the fact that $\|P_F\| \leq 1$ for all $F\subset\subset\xi$

Comment: So $U_y$ should be something like
\begin{equation}
U_y = \{ z \in H : \| z - y \| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \}
\end{equation}
Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this in the case that $\xi$ is a countable orthonormal basis. As my solution is too long for a comment, I am typing it here in hopes that it will aid you in the general case.
$$ $$
To be concrete regarding our assumption that $\xi$ is a countable orthonormal basis, write $\xi = \{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we must show that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $h \in \overline{B}(0,1) := \{h: ||h|| \leq 1\}$,
$$\bigg|\bigg|Th -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle Th, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| \leq \varepsilon.$$
$$ $$
Since $T$ is a compact operator, $T\left(\overline{B}(0,1)\right)$ is relatively compact; in particular, it is uniformly bounded.  Thus, $T\left(\overline{B}(0,1)\right)$ can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$. Choose such a cover by balls centered at $\{y_1, …, y_n\}$.  For $j = 1,…,n$, $y_j = h_j$ for some $h_j \in \overline{B}(0,1)$.  For each $j$ the sum
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\langle Th_j, e_k \rangle e_k$$
converges to $y_j$.  In particular, there exists $N_j$ so that
$$\bigg|\bigg|y_j -\sum_{k=1}^{N_j} \langle Th_j, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$  Let $N = \max_j N_j$.

Let $h \in \overline{B}(0,1)$ be arbitrary.  Then there exists $j$ so that $||Th-y_j||< \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$.  Now, we have
$$\bigg|\bigg|Th -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle Th, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| \leq \bigg|\bigg|y_j -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle y_j, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| + \bigg|\bigg|(Th-y_j) -\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle Th, e_k \rangle e_k - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle y_j, e_k \rangle e_k \right) \bigg|\bigg| = \bigg|\bigg|y_j -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle y_j, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| + \bigg|\bigg|(Th-y_j) -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle (Th-y_j), e_k \rangle e_k -  \bigg|\bigg| \, \, \, \, (\star)$$
$$
 \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} +\bigg|\bigg|Th -y_j\bigg|\bigg| +
\bigg| \bigg| \sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle (Th-y_j),e_k \rangle e_k \bigg| \bigg|.$$
By our assumption that $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis along with lemma 1 (below), 
$$\bigg| \bigg| \sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle (Th-y_j),e_k \rangle e_k \bigg| \bigg| \leq \bigg|\bigg|Th -y_j\bigg|\bigg|.$$
Thus, $(\star)$ becomes
$$\bigg|\bigg|Th -\sum_{k=1}^{N} \langle Th, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg|\bigg| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + 2 \bigg|\bigg|Th -y_j\bigg|\bigg| \leq \varepsilon.$$

$$ $$
$$ $$
Lemma 1: Let $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $H$.  Then for any $x \in H$ and for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$\bigg| \bigg| \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k \bigg| \bigg| \leq ||x||.$$

Proof: For concision, let $\Sigma$ denote $\sum_{k = 1}^{N} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$.  Then we have
$$0 \leq ||x-\Sigma||^2 = ||x||^2 - 2 \text{Re}(\langle x, \Sigma \rangle) + ||\Sigma||^2 \, \, \, \, (\dagger).$$
Note that 
$$\langle x, \Sigma \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big\langle x, \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k \big \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \overline{\langle x, e_k \rangle} \langle x, e_k \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{N}|\langle x, e_k \rangle|^2 = ||\Sigma||^2.$$
Thus, $(\dagger)$ becomes $$0 \leq ||x|| - ||\Sigma||.$$